# How to close more than one window with a single click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to close two windows at the same time when user click the Start button, the new window will pop-up and when the user clicks the Exit button on the Second pop-up window than both the window should Close at a time.

I know that for a different window I have to create a separate function to exit windows But I want to close more than one window with a single click.

I'm using python 3.7!

```
import tkinter

def NewWindow():

    def qExit():
        root.destroy()

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("New Window")
    newButton = tkinter.Button(root, text=" Click here  to Exit:",
                                command=qExit)
    newButton.pack()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    root.mainloop()


Window = tkinter.Tk()
Window.title("hello")
eButton = tkinter.Button(Window, text="Start", command=NewWindow)
eButton.pack()
Window.geometry("200x200")
Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello! I recommend you to fix the indentation in your sample code. As it is, it's unclear where your functions start and end.

Comment: can you help me with this ??

Comment: @Valentino: Indentation looks fine to me.

Comment: did you tried `Window.destroy()` in `qExit()` ?

Comment: @martineau indentation is fine now. The OP edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `tkinter.Tk()` more than once in a `tkinter` application. Call [`Toplevel()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) if you want to create a new window.

You also generally don't need to call `mainloop()` more than once.

To close both the new window and the main window, you can pass the latter to the former when you create it, and then `destroy()` that in your `qExit()` function (as well as the new window itself).

Note I changed some of the function and variable names to conform more to the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

```
import tkinter

def makeWindow(parent):

    def qExit():
        newWindow.destroy()
        parent.destroy()

    newWindow = tkinter.Toplevel()
    newWindow.geometry("300x200")
    newWindow.title("New Window")
    newButton = tkinter.Button(newWindow, text=" Click here  to Exit",
                               command=qExit)
    newButton.pack()


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("hello")
eButton = tkinter.Button(root, text="Start", command=lambda: makeWindow(root))
eButton.pack()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to just do exit() to stop the program, which will close all windows. alternatively you can make a list of all open window objects and call destroy on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

No need description

```
def qExit():
    root.destroy()
    Window.destroy()
```